# How to simplify polyline while preserving corners?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-vision

I'm trying to write a simple "vectorizer" for my CG project. The goal is to vectorize characters / shapes in a binary-valued image.

My approach is:

1.delete every black pixel with 4 surrounding pixels (diagonal excluded)

2.scan the image and group connected pixels (diaganol included)

3.use Ramer–Douglas–Peucker(RDP) algorithm on each group of points

4.use polyline or b-spline to connect points in each group

But the result is a little disappointing. The RDP doesn't simplify it enough, say, if I input a list of points in the shape of a square, it should reduce it to only four corners.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEStF.png) is an example that shows the above problem. The pink ones are pixels after RDP simplification, which are still too many.

Here's the code I write in C++/Qt, if needed. (There are some redundant codes but I think there's nothing wrong)

```c
QList<T> rdp(const QList<T> & list, double eps = 2) {//reduce the number of points in a curve
    QStack<QPoint> stk;
    stk.append({ 0,list.size() - 1 });
    bool* indices = new bool[list.size()];
    for(int i=0,n=list.size();i<n;++i){
        indices[i]=true;
    }
    while (!stk.empty()) {
        auto t = stk.pop();
        int s, id = s = t.x(), e = t.y();
        if(e-s<=1){
            break;
        }
        auto p = list[s]-list[e];
        double dmax = 0, len=sqrt(pow(p.x(), 2) + pow(p.y(), 2));
        for (int i = id + 1; i < e; ++i) {
            if (indices[i]) {
                auto q = list[i]-list[e];
                double d=0;
                if (len < 1e-3) {
                    d = sqrt(pow(q.x(), 2) + pow(q.y(), 2));
                }else{
                    d = abs(p.x() * q.y() - p.y() * q.x()) / len;
                }
                if (d > dmax) {
                    id = i;
                    dmax = d;
                }
            }
        }
        if (dmax > eps) {
            stk.append({ s,id });
            stk.append({ id,e });
        } else {
            for (int i = s + 1; i < e; ++i) {
                indices[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    QList<T> re;
    for (int i = 0, j = list.size(); i < j; ++i) {
        if (indices[i]) {
            re.append(list[i]);
        }
    }
    delete[] indices;
    return re;
}
```

Any suggestions on my approach/code or other better approaches are welcomed.

Comment: Please don't use the C tag for C++ questions

Comment: I do not understand this part: `if (abs(x1) + abs(x2) < 1e-3) d = sqrt(pow(x2 - 0.5 * x1, 2) + pow(y2 - 0.5 * x1, 2));`. What is it supposed to do? What happens if you just remove that part?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I see the problem here. That's supposed to prevent numerical unstalbeness but I did it wrong. Now I've fixed the bug and it works. Thank you :)